# Compare-Object Filenames to Variable for Later Reference

Tags: loops, powershell, compare, subdirectory, copy-item

I am newer to PowerShell but I am determined to press through the learning curves, and need some additional help.

I am comparing files between sub directories, using Compare-Object, and it works and returns the list of all differences.

I need to populate the differences (file names) into an array/variable (?) and then reference the file name(s) to copy the file(s) to a specified location.

```
[string] $CopyFromPath = "C:\folder"
[string] $TargetCopyPath = "D:\folder"


Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $SourceFileSet -DifferenceObject ($TargetParentPath + $child) |
    Select @{
        n = "$($child.ToUpper()) (Missing data in $TargetCopyPath)"
        e = {$_.InputObject}
    } | ft


foreach($f in $MissingFile) {
    Copy-Item -Path ($CopyFromPath + "\" + $MissingFile) -Destination $TargetCopyPath
}
```

It's probably very simple and my approach may be overkill but any input would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is confusing. Too many variables that aren't defined or passed in.  I assume `$SourceFileSet` is the output of `Get-ChildItem` on one of your folders?  What is `$child` and `$MissingFile`?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. 

Yes, $SourceFileSet refers to all files populated by Get-ChildItem. $child refers to the subfolder under parent path which is declared earlier in code but not included in snippet. $MissingFile refers to an individual file returned by Compare-Object list. Again, I'm in the early stages of PS programming.

Comment: Are you trying to copy all the files from folder A to folder B without overwriting the files which are already in folder B? Or are you trying to do something more complex?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to copy files from folder A to folder B without overwriting the files which are already in folder B.